# Jacoco lost test. Coverage always 0

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Jacoco plugin lost JUnit tests, report always 0% but the test exists. I think the problem is my `pom.xml`.  Help me find the mistake.

[Pom.xml on GitHub](https://github.com/triodjangopiter/bridge/blob/master/pom.xml)

Perhaps its conflict with `checkstyle` plugin?

Part with Jacoco setting:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*IT*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>PACKAGE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.0</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No tests executed, so no coverage.

---

In [build log](https://github.com/triodjangopiter/bridge/runs/1326109008#step:4:1635) you have

```
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

which is probably due to `-DskipTests` in your [.github/workflows/build.yml](https://github.com/triodjangopiter/bridge/blob/847638a7c37b5c36dce0ada679403973db764f56/.github/workflows/build.yml#L21)

```
run: mvn -B clean package -DskipTests
```

---

Execution of `mvn test` produces

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ bridge ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

because you have `junit-jupiter` in dependencies,
but don't have `junit-vintage-engine` (see output of `mvn dependency:tree`),
while your tests are written using JUnit 4.

---

After the following removal of exclusion of `junit-vintage-engine`

```
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
+            <!--
             <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                     <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                     <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
+            -->
```

Execution of `mvn test` produces

```
[INFO] Tests run: 47, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

and the following report

[image: report]

Comment: local test takes the same result. I'm stuck on the local test config step. I remove `-DskipTests` but nothing to change.